# Java: URL or String?

Tags: java, oop, coding-style

Is there any merit (coding style, OOP best practice, etc.) in working with an instance of `java.net.URL` as opposed to `java.lang.String` when I can be reasonably certain that a URL is valid anyway (perhaps I've specified it statically in a properties file) and I will just be working with it in its string form anyway (for example printing it in a JSP file)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`java.net.URL`'s equals is broken. You should use `java.net.URI`. You should pass objects around whenever possible rather than Strings. It saves programmer errors, for example getting method parameters the wrong way round - the compiler won't pick it up if they're both Strings.

Comment: isn't that because it actually fetches the documents to compare?

Comment: @Richard H; it's because it tries to resolve the host names and compare IP numbers rather than host names, which actually isn't just bad but also wrong, at least regarding HTTP which has virtual hosts.

Comment: what about URL.sameFile(other URL)?

Answer (score 0):

You will get many method support in case or URL. but if its just to display then go for String you can always build URL from valid String

Comment: It's easier getting a string from a URI/URL object (calling `toString()`) than it is to make a URI/URL from a string (which can trigger `MalformedURLException`s), so I'd probably vote for going with URI/URL objects regardless of intended usage.

Answer (score 0):

Well the [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class has lots of methods that let you manipulate the url, for example get the host, the path and a dozen other things. You can also open a connection to the URL and fetch the document if you need.